# PHP readInnerXML returns blank string

Tags: php, xml

I'm not sure what is happening. I have this code:

```
`case (XMLREADER::ELEMENT):
 $node_type = $reader->nodeType;

 $node_name = $reader->name;

  if ($node_name == "gs_relay_rpc"){//I need this to work now

   $node_value = $reader->readInnerXML();

   get_xml_data("<gs_relay > ".$node_value."</gs_relay>");

   include($rpc_folder.$node_name.".php");
  }`
```

which is obviously part of a switch statement and it works perfectly. Then I have this code :

```
 `case (XMLREADER::ELEMENT):
 $node_type = $reader->nodeType;
 echo $node_type."->";
 $node_name = $reader->name;

  if ($node_name == "itp_exchange_rpc"){
   echo $node_name." = ";
   $reader->read();

   $node_value = $reader->readInnerXML();
   get_xml_data("<test > ".$node_value."</test>");

  } else {
   echo $node_name." = ";
   $reader->read();
   $node_value = $reader->value;
   echo $node_value."<br>";
  }`
```

Which is practically a carbon copy of the first block but with this second block `readInnerXML()` returns a blank. The xml chunk is valid because it does get parsed. My problem is that I need to recurse on it but I can't since the function returns blank.

The xml: 
    `<itp_exchange_rpc > <itp_floor > <itp_floor_name > test@hotmail.com</itp_floor_name> </itp_floor></itp_exchange_rpc>`

Comment: Can anyone help shed some light

Comment: Is there a more reliable method other then readInnerXML to get me the nested xml chunk?

Comment: The error msg: `Warning: XMLReader::XML() [xmlreader.xml]: Empty string supplied as input in...`

Comment: The error is raised when I remove the test tags from the recursion

Comment: The two blocks are in two separate and unrelated script files

Comment: Ahhh, the world, it seems, IS bigger than the internet. Google searches have started returning my own question. How 'bout that!

Comment: Can I debug the inner workings of readInnerXML by some other means? I won't like to use another parser just because of this issue. It's working fine in other script files... Is God smiting me :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out God was smiting me. It took a car crash in the morning to show me I had one too many `reader->read()` in the second block. I'm getting the string fine now.